# Can I use custom ReflectiveInjector strategies to get component providers?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-di

As you all know we have different strategies for providers: `useClass`, `useExisting`, `useFactory`, `useValue`. But what if I would like to add own strategy? Something like:

```
providers: [ { MyService: MyService, useAsyncFactory: MyAsyncFactory} ]
```

What is the best way to **extend ReflectiveInjector** and make Angular use your extended variant? I found [the place](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/di/reflective_provider.ts#L103) where it's defined, but still looking for a way to overwrite existing Angular DI mechanism.

---

*P.S.: Please don't ask why I need it and why not to use existing strategies. I'm doing research about Angular DI and the answer will help me to understand it better.*

Comment: do you then want to use it in the production? it won't work for providers registered through components because Angular doesn't use ReflectiveInjector to resolve providers on components

Comment: that was actually my question: how to make Angular use your own Injector instead of ReflectiveInjector

Comment: Angular doesn't use any injector for component providers

Comment: sorry, it look like I read you fist message not attentive enough, but what makes you say so?

Comment: see [this function](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L394)

Comment: but anyway for normal dependancies it will call injector - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L392

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149570/discussion-between-stepan-suvorov-and-maximus).

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood Angular doesn't use `ReflectiveInjector` to retrieve component providers so even if you manage to extend ReflectiveInjector it will have no effect on the component providers. You can see it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L394):

```
 function resolveDep(...) {
       ...
        default:
          const providerDef =
              (allowPrivateServices ? elDef.element !.allProviders :
                                      elDef.element !.publicProviders) ![tokenKey];
          if (providerDef) {
            const providerData = asProviderData(view, providerDef.index);
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            if (providerData.instance === NOT_CREATED) {
              providerData.instance = _createProviderInstance(view, providerDef);
            }
            return providerData.instance;
          }
```

The method is called when component requests a dependency, for example `ViewContainerRef`:

```
class MyComponent {
   constructor(vc: ViewContainerRef)
```

And this line:

```
const providerData = asProviderData(view, providerDef.index);
```

shows that dependency is retrieved from the view node, not a reflective injector. So when you do like this:

```
constructor(i: Injector) {
   console.log(i instanceOf ReflectiveInjector); // false
}
```

you will see that it's not real. [It's just a wrapper](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L320-L330) around `resolveDep` function which encloses over the view and relevant view node.

Reflective injector is still used for the host view injectors. This is the injector that you pass when you instantiate a component dynamically:

```
componentFactory.create(hostViewInjector)
```

[Here is](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L411) the relevant code:

```
const value = startView.root.injector.get(depDef.token, NOT_FOUND_CHECK_ONLY_ELEMENT_INJECTOR);
```

And also the module injector is consulted if you the dependency cannot be resolved on the component or the host view injector. 
[Here is](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L423) the relevant code:

```
return startView.root.ngModule.injector.get(depDef.token, notFoundValue);
```