# Karma - ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges mocking

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have an issue with cdr.detectChanges() in my test. I have an error happening when it's called and I don't have any information, I just get this error :

> ZoneAwareError@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:923:0 <-
>   config/karma-shim.js:108645:28
>       invokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:398:0 <- config/karma-shim.js:108120:36
>       onInvokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:103:0 <- config/karma-shim.js:107642:49

Is there a way to make detectChanges work?

I also tried something else by trying to make detectChanges do nothing by defining cdr in my test component configuration like this :

```
cdr = {
  detectChanges: () => {}
}
```

and then in the providers `{ provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useValue: cdr }`, but when I console.info the cdr in the method tested it seems I still have the original cdr class.

I also tried with a fake class defined like this :

```
class FakeCDR {
  detectChanges(): void {

  }
}
```

and then `{ provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useClass: FakeCDR }` in the providers, but same here.

Here's my test code:

```
it('should create an user', fakeAsync(inject([MockBackend],
  (backend: MockBackend) => {
    fixture.detectChanges()
    tick()

    component.newUser = User.newUserDraft()
    component.newUser.email = "email@gmail.com"
    component.createUser()
    tick()

    expect(component.newUser.email).toBe(User.newUserDraft().email)
  })))
```

and in createUser it's doing a service.createUser then do some stuff then cdr.detectChanges(). I did put console.info at every lines so I'm sure it's at the detectChanges that it fails.

Comment: show your test code, Change Detector is not provided through DI, it's a different mechanism, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186982/2545680)

Comment: Added the test code, but it probably won't help you

Comment: @Guigui, Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi, Is is not injected through DI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: How to mock ChangeDetectorRef while unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421807/angular-2-how-to-mock-changedetectorref-while-unit-testing)

Answer (score 1):

First some considerations:

1. `ChangeDetectorRef` is not provided through DI, so you cannot provide a double.
2. `fixture.changeDetectorRef` is not the same as the component provided, so you cannot use this.
3. `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef)` will create a new instance of the private class `ViewRef` (the public class `ViewRef` is just an alias for `ViewRef$1`), every time it is invoked, then the object provided to the component is another.

So my solution is:

```
const changeDetectorRef = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef);
const detectChangesSpy = spyOn(changeDetectorRef.constructor.prototype, 'detectChanges');
```