# Angular 4 are services provided in a core module singleton for real?

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I'm trying to understand core module and singleton services in angular 4.
The official documentation (https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule) says the following things:

> UserService is an application-wide singleton. You don't want each
>   module to have its own separate instance. Yet there is a real danger
>   of that happening if the SharedModule provides the UserService.
>
> CoreModule provides the UserService. Angular registers that provider
>   with the app root injector, making a singleton instance of the
>   UserService available to any component that needs it, whether that
>   component is eagerly or lazily loaded.
>
> We recommend collecting such single-use classes and hiding their
>   details inside a CoreModule. A simplified root AppModule imports
>   CoreModule in its capacity as orchestrator of the application as a
>   whole.

```
import { CommonModule }      from '@angular/common';
import { TitleComponent }    from './title.component';
import { UserService }       from './user.service';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf }       from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ TitleComponent ],
  exports:      [ TitleComponent ],
  providers:    [ UserService ]
})
export class CoreModule {
    constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) { ... }
}
```

So I'm using the Core Module providing singleton services, and the constructor

```
constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) { ... }
```

prevent to import the Core Module more than one time.

**1) BUT, what if I provide the UserService in another module (e.g in a lazy-loading module) ? This lazy-loaded module has a new instance of the service?**

And about forRoot method:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  providers:    [ UserService ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}

static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: CoreModule,
    providers: [
      {provide: UserServiceConfig, useValue: config }
    ]
  };
}
}
```

2) If I import the CoreModule using CoreModule.forRoot() in the AppModule, what happen to the UserService ? Is it provided too?

Thanks

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242774/2545680) help?

Comment: Yes you guys both helped me understanding a bit better what's going on... I still have to have a look at the links you provided. I'm still confused when/why should I use Core Module with forRoot method and lazy-loaded modules, and if the services provided in the coreModule are really application-wide singleton, or is the forRoot method that bring them singleton

Comment: okay, read the links I've provided and then ask clarifying questions

Comment: hey, is there anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242774/2545680)?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is confusing, particularly this line:

> UserService is an application-wide singleton. You don't want each
>   module to have its own separate instance. **Yet there is a real danger
>   of that happening if the SharedModule provides the UserService**.

There's no danger of that happening if you don't use lazy loaded modules. Let's see an example. You have `A` module that imports `B` module. Both modules define providers:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: {provide: 'b', 'b'}
})
export class BModule {}

@NgModule({
   imports: [AModule]
   providers: {provide: 'a', 'a'}
})
export class AModule {}
```

What happens when the compiler generates a module factory is that it **merges** these providers together and factory **only for one module** will be created. Here is how it will look:

```
var AModuleNgFactory = jit_createNgModuleFactory0(

    // reference to the module class
    jit_AppModule1,  

    // array of bootstrap components
    [jit_AppComponent2],

    function (_l) {
        return jit_moduleDef3([

            // array of providers
            jit_moduleProvideDef4(256, 'b', 'b', []),
            jit_moduleProvideDef4(256, 'a', 'a', [])
            ...,
        ]);
```

You can see that the providers are merged. Now, if you define two modules with the **same provider token**, the modules will be merged and the providers from the module that imports the other will override the imported module providers:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: {provide: 'a', 'b'}
})
export class BModule {}

@NgModule({
   imports: [AModule]
   providers: {provide: 'a', 'a'}
})
export class AModule {}
```

The factory definition will look like this now:

```
function (_l) {
    return jit_moduleDef3([

        // array of providers
        jit_moduleProvideDef4(256, 'a', 'a', []),
        ...,
    ]);
```

So no matter how many modules you import, only one factory with merged providers is created. And only one root injector is created. The injector that components create is not "real" injector - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186982/2545680) to understand why.

> This lazy-loaded module has a new instance of the service?

When it comes to lazy loaded modules, Angular generates **separate** factories for them. It means that providers defined in them are not merged into the main module injector. So if a lazy loaded module defines the provider with the same token, Angular will create new instance of that service even if there's already one in the main module injector.

> If I import the CoreModule using CoreModule.forRoot() in the AppModule

To understand what `forRoot` does, see [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES) vs RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680396/2545680).

Comment: I asked on the angular room in gitter, and you are right! Only lazy loaded modules have their own injectors that are children from the root one.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, great, maybe you can upvote my answer then)

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes. This relates to the fact that the dependency injector is **hierarchical**.

This means, every module has a set of elements that can be injected (module level), and if one of its elements requires a dependency which doesn't isnt present at a module level, then the dependency injector will look for the dependency in the parent of the module (the one module that imported it), and so on until it finds the dependency or reaches the root (app.module), where it will throw an error if the dependency cant be resolved (hierarchy level).

2) Yes, the `UserService` will be provided. `forRoot` will create a **different** "version" of the `CoreModule`, in which the "normal" CoreModule is expanded with the extra properties that you add.

In most cases, `forRoot` will take the "normal" version of the module and include the providers array, to ensure that services are singleton. The "normal" version of the module, will only have components, pipes or other non singletone elements.

Take as example the `TranslateModule` of [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/index.ts) (extracted relevant section):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TranslatePipe,
        TranslateDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        TranslatePipe,
        TranslateDirective
    ]
}) // this defines the normal version of the module
export class TranslateModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders { // this kinda tells "module + providers"
        return {
            ngModule: TranslateModule, // take the normal version
            providers: [ // merge this to the providers array of the normal version
                TranslateStore,
                TranslateService
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Maybe this resource could be useful as further explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VLYjt81-fE

Comment: Thanks, so for point 1) the developers should care about it, there is no secure 100% way to have a single instance of the service 2) If I use forRoot method, the provides array at the @NgModule({..}) section is useless

Comment: 1) Yup, as I mentioned, is pretty easy to create module level instances of providers, which would be injected instead of the hierarchical ones. 2) Yes, in most of the cases you would add providers to the foorRoot method. Ill update my answer with further explanatio

Comment: Corrected my answer to your 2nd point, I missed something before :)

Comment: `forRoot` doesn't do anything, it's the same as defining a module with providers

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't do anything? It does, it creates a new module by wrapping an existing one and adding providers to it

Comment: @Jota I still don't get if the fact that services are singleton is because they are defined in the Core Module (forced to be imported only once by its weird constructor) or because I import it using forRoot()  ... In fact you said: "In most cases, forRoot will take the "normal" version of the module and include the providers array, to ensure that services are singleton". The official doc says that the forRoot is used to configure the core services, not to keep them singleton...

Comment: ...and looking at the example you posted, why should I use the forRoot method  without providing a configuration as parameter of forRoot ? What's the goal to import the core Module using forRoot if I don't provide an external configuration? (as shown in the official doc (https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#configure-core-services-with-coremoduleforroot)

Comment: It doesnt make sense to have a CoreModule with a forRoot method, as it should only be imported by the root module, so having different versions of it would defeat its purpose. I removed some elements from the example to just explain the most relevant ideas (having 2 versions of the same module, one with and other without providers). You can ofc pass parameters to it, but it is not mandatory. I could recommend you this other resource if you still feel confused: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o

Comment: @user2010955, read [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES) vs RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498081/routermodule-forrootroutes-vs-routermodule-forchildroutes/44680396#44680396). It should clarify why `forRoot` is used. Usually, you don't need to implement it on your custom modules

Comment: @Jota.Toledo,  _it creates a new module by wrapping an existing one and adding providers to it_ - it doesn't create anything. It's just a convenience approach to importing a module with providers when providers are not known beforehand. Read the answer in my comment above

Comment: Thats a nice explanation. You are right there, that was a poor choice of words. I wanted to say that it creates an object that wraps a module and add providers to it. In the end, its an augmented version of the wrapped module.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, hierarchy of modules is not created if one module imports the other. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242774/2545680).

Comment: Ill create a repo to try this out :P

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to summarize what I think to have learned:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  providers:    [ 
    UserService,
    UserServiceConfig
    ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}

static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: CoreModule,
    providers: [
      {provide: UserServiceConfig, useValue: config }
    ]
  };
}
}
```

When I import the module using the forRoot method:

- UserService is also provided since (as you guys explained) the forRoot creates an extended version of this module (it merges the services)
- UserServiceConfig is provided using the config argument of the forRoot method.

**And regarding application-wide singleton:**

In order to have application-wide singleton services (even for lazy-loaded modules) I can use the forRoot method:

```
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: MyModule,
    providers: [
      MySingletonService
    ]
  };
```

- the forRoot must be called only once in the appModule (so why the method is called "forRoot" by convention)
- if the module is imported in multiple modules, MySingletonService is not been provided (because it's provided only through the forRoot method)

**BUT**

If I create a CoreModule with a following special constructor, it prevents the module to be loaded more than once, so the services provided are application-wide singleton:

```
constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
  if (parentModule) {
    throw new Error(
      'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
  }
}
```

So it makes sense to use forRoot method in a SharedModule, not in a module with a special constructor above.

So If I want application-wide (even for lazy-modules) services I see two options:

1. Shared Module with forRoot method called in the appModule
2. Core Module with special constructor and services provided normally, without  a forRoot method

Any comments?